# How do I stop retrying when a particular exception occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-rq

I'm enqueing my tasks like this:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, Retry

queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
queue.enqueue("path.to.my.func", retry=Retry(max=3), on_failure=my_failure)
```

And then on the failure callback I want to stop the next retry if a particular exception occurs:

```
def my_failure(job, connection, type, value, traceback):
    if type == MyException:
        # do not continue retrying!
```

I'm not sure if the `on_failure` is the right way to do it.

Comment: You could set a global variable that the queuing code checks.